# Using CocoaAsyncSocket to receive UDP in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, udp, cocoaasyncsocket

I am trying to receive broadcast UDP packets on iOS. I've verified that the packets are being sent (I can see them in another iOS app on the same device).

CocoaAsyncSocket seemed like the most straightforward library to do this with. I added the framework to my project using Carthage. Following the [example](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket/blob/master/Examples/RunLoop/UdpEchoServer/UdpEchoServer/AppDelegate.m) in Objective-C, I have an iOS app with not much else in it, and this view being loaded:

```
import UIKit
import CocoaAsyncSocket

class FirstViewController: UIViewController 
    var sock:AsyncUdpSocket?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if (sock == nil){
            sock = AsyncUdpSocket(delegate: self)
        }
        do{
            try sock!.bindToPort(54545)
            try sock!.enableBroadcast(true) // Also tried without this line
            sock!.receiveWithTimeout(10,tag: 0)
        } catch {
            print("error")
        }
        print("View Loaded...")
    }

    func onUdpSocket(cbsock:AsyncUdpSocket!,
                     didReceiveData data: NSData!){
        print("Recv...")
        print(data)
        cbsock.receiveWithTimeout(10, tag: 0)
    }
}
```

In either the Simulator, or on a device, in the debug console, I see the "View loaded..." message, but nothing from the callback, neither the "Recv..." or the data. It seems the callback isn't being called, but I am not getting any errors either. I've tried other timeouts, and various tweaks like making functions and classes public, but no luck.

I've written a receiver in Python, but this has me stumped.

EDIT: `sock` now used as a property at paulw's suggestion

Comment: You want your `sock` variable to be a property, not a local variable.  With your current code, as soon as `viewDidLoad` exits the socket object will be released

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11, I see why that is needed.

Comment: @SpencerOgden, did changing `sock` to be a property help?  The way it is in your code, it is an instance variable, not a local one, so the `sock` object should not be released upon exiting `viewDidLoad`.